# (html) wysiwyg editor for TEXT fields in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wysiwyg

i'm making a small website and i need whoever takes over to add some content, stored in three tables which by sep '13 will have at most 500 records (small stuff). right now i'm using phpmyadmin, but adding text (one of the tables is a mini blog) requires basic html skills, which i'm sure "whoever takes over" doesn't have. do you know, alternatively:

a) a way to integrate a wysiwyg editor with phpmyadmin (at least for the TEXT fields)

b) an essential frontend to mysql which supports editing tables (just the content, not the structure) – in which i might embed an editor myself?

**edit**: thanks for the editor suggestions, but that's a secondary problem: at the moment i'd need a way to embed any such editor to phpmyadmin (otherwise i'd have to write the frontend myself)...

Comment: "WYSIWYG editor for TEXT fields" makes no sense, because there is no "What You Get" involved in TEXT fields. You need to emphasize that you are storing **HTML** in these fields. Now, it makes sense to have "WYSIWYG editor for HTML contents to be stored in MySQL TEXT fields"...

Comment: sure, it is a comment, not a reply (aka "Answer")

Comment: Have you considered building a basic admin interface for crud operations?

Answer (score 1):

I think CK editor is what you are looking for, you can see for yourself here: http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: hmmm, yeah, i've seen it; that would work for either b) - unfortunately i lack the frontend itself; having a ready-made one which is not a massive blog platform would help... - or a) in case there is an easy way to embed it in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for you, I have to say that doing this is completely wrong, but if you really need it, then here is the way:

Get TinyMCE from here:

http://www.tinymce.com/

Extract the package in your phpmyadmin folder, for example in my case I put the main contents here: `D:\Program Files\Wamp\apps\phpmyadmin\tiny_mce` so the `tiny_mce.js` file is located at this patch `D:\Program Files\Wamp\apps\phpmyadmin\tiny_mce\tiny_mce.js`

Then open the file `tbl_change.php` in your phpmyadmin folder and add the flowing code after `<?php`:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>'
.'<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">'
.'tinyMCE.init({'
.'theme : "advanced",'
.'mode : "textareas",'
.'language : "en"'
.'});'
.'</script>';
```

This will add the TinyMCE in all textareas of editing a record in phpmyadmin, if you needed it somewhere else, just take a look at what file is being loaded in phpmyadmin right iframe, and add that code to that file too.

I repeat that doing this is completely wrong, just do it if you really need it.

Comment: what's the problem specific problem with it, aside from the fact that it "looks" dirty? :)

Comment: Looking dirty isn't the main problem, since at this point, modern browsers will take care of it, you aren't designing a website here, so don't be worry for this one, the main problem is that TinyMCE adds or optimizes HTML codes some times, imagine that you are editing your USERS table and you don't need this in there, but it will be loaded on your ADDRESS field if it's TEXT type and then TinyMCE may add a <p></p> on contents of that field. I suggest to have this code commented and uncomment it when you are going to edit HTML data in your database.

Answer (score 0):

I am using jHtmlArea, a jQuery plugin, as a very simple and quick way to implement a solution for a case just like yours: http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/

It is really really simple to use it, in the front-end. But I have not used phpMyAdmin nor any other "essential frontend". I have coded a simple back-end PHP script to save the contents into the database.

In the back-end, I am also using [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to clean the HTML, and [HTML Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) to prettify it.

Answer (score 0):

This is also useful TinyMCE "www.tinymce.com" , this WYSIWYG  is seen in wordpress