# How to add a custom editor to phpMyAdmin for certain fields only?

Tags: php, serialization, phpmyadmin, editor, customization

I would like to integrate [`JSON Editor Online`](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditoronline) with [`phpMyAdmin`](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) so as to edit certain table fields which contain PHP arrays encoded in JSON format.

I went through the [Configuration options](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config) and the only ones related to field editors were:

```
CharEditing: Which editor should be used for CHAR/VARCHAR fields
```

I read this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448851/html-wysiwyg-editor-for-text-fields-in-phpmyadmin) which points to `tbl_change.php` but can't see any easy way of customizing it.

I wish we could do something like this:

- define which fields need the custom editor (e.g. based on criteria such as data type, field name...)
- associate these fields with the name of the custom editor
- create the custom editor in a normalized way (using JS we could describe how the field value is loaded into the editor and which event/value to use to save the edited value back into the `DB`.

**Does anybody know about a way of adding a custom editor to phpMyAdmin for certain fields only?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for plugins to customize editor right now.

However you can quite easily change used editor for some fields in `libraries/insert_edit.lib.php` - change function `PMA_getValueColumn`, which is responsible for getting HTML code for field edit.

PS: The above is about upcoming phpMyAdmin 4.0, I'm not sure about older versions.

Answer (score 1):

i search on phpmyadmin files i found two file that i think is related to this

`sql.php` and `libraries/display_tbl.lib.php` i have one idea in `display_tbl.lib.php` is one variable

```
line 1293: $grid_edit_class = 'grid_edit';
```

this is the name of class that phpmyadmin editor with this class name find field that is editable.
 you can change it to something else like `grid_edit2` with this work now phpmyadmin editor is disable.

`gis_data_editor.js` is phpmyadmin  editor that include in `sql.php`

now you can include your editor files in `sql.php` and set `grid_edit2` for your editor but you have one another problem on save edited field.

in my search it is down by `makegrid.js`  you can see post script on line 29 you should compatible your editor with this script or write your own post script for send edited data to `tbl_replace.php` this is a sample of post data header

```
ajax_request:true
sql_query:
token:0203ddaa0c51d4776e93921e6ca1281f
db:sepidarsoft_portal
table:archive_media
clause_is_unique:1
where_clause[]:`archive_media`.`_id` = 45
fields[multi_edit][0][]:1364198434
fields_name[multi_edit][0][]:UTime
fields_null[multi_edit][0][]:
rel_fields_list:
do_transformations:false
transform_fields_list:
relational_display:K
goto:sql.php
submit_type:save
_nocache:1364974511419938233
```

hope this information help you

Comment: Thanks for the research. As I suspected, it seems like there isn't a nice way to plug additional editors. I've emailed the authors of phpMyAdmin about it, waiting to hear back from them.