# get text from mysql which formatted by WYSIWYG

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wysiwyg

In my website I'm useing to input datas a WYSIWYG editor (sceditor). It's working perfect, but when i want to write to index.php the article which I formatted, I only see [b]Hellow word![/b]

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [(html) wysiwyg editor for TEXT fields in phpmyadmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448851/html-wysiwyg-editor-for-text-fields-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: @user3540050 Did you find an answer that answers [your question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215947/variables-name-will-be-the-value-of-another-variable-in-php/)? If so, could you 'tick' it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this snippet, it looks like you have sceditor initialized to save text as BBCODE, not xHTML. Check the script options for [intializing sceditor](http://www.sceditor.com/documentation/getting-started/).